# javascript - calling callback with parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback

I'm trying to to run a script that will wait for 1 second between loop calls. but the code won't recognize the i parameter.

```
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          var scanProgressInterval = setInterval(function(i) {
          // Process the line, noting it might be incomplete.
            if (lines[i].indexOf("(y/n)") > -1) {
              console.log("includes  (y/n)");
              ws.emit('scan', JSON.stringify({scan: false, question: lines[i]}));
            }
            else if (lines[i].indexOf("any key") > -1) {
              console.log("any key");
              ws.emit('scan', JSON.stringify({scan: false, key: lines[i]}));
            }
          }, 1000);
      }
```

what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Why not use setTimeout with an external counter and repeat it until the counter reaches 0 or 1000 or whatever? Don't overcomplicate your life. It's already complicated enough.

Comment: setInterval(function(i) {
..........
}, 1000, i);

this will pass the parameter i to the setInterval function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here 'i' is globally declared.

Try using your function as a closure.

```
      function scanProgressInterval(i){ 
          setInterval(function() {
              // Process the line, noting it might be incomplete.
                if (lines[i].indexOf("(y/n)") > -1) {
                  console.log("includes  (y/n)");
                  ws.emit('scan', JSON.stringify({scan: false, question: lines[i]}));
                }
                else if (lines[i].indexOf("any key") > -1) {
                  console.log("any key");
                  ws.emit('scan', JSON.stringify({scan: false, key: lines[i]}));
                }
              }, 1000);
      }

     for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          scanProgressInterval(i);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the params *behind* the timout:

> setInterval(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` here: `setInterval(function(i) {...` is in the scope of the `setInterval()` function, which means that it has no value because when the callback function is called inside the `setInterval()` function, it will have **no argument** passed.

You don't need to put the `i` as parameter of the callback in `setInterval()`. Simply remove it because you can already access `i` within the loop itself.